# Adding variable inside quotes in a python script

Tags: python, bash, curl

I'm writing a python script to automate some bash commands and am having trouble with passing a variable inside the curl command. This is what I have:

`subprocess.call('''curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X PUT -d '{"name": "{}".format(someVariable), "hive_ql": "CREATE VIEW user_balance AS SELECT NAME, LOB,ACCOUNT,BALANCE FROM csvtable"}' localhost:someport/api''', shell=True)`

I'm trying to pass a variable in for the 'name' parameter, denoted by 'someVariable' in this example. But I get an error stating:

`"message": "Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 14 (char 13):`

When I replace the format part with an actual string, the script executes just fine so I know I'm doing something wrong with passing the variable between the quotes, just not sure what the correct syntax is.

Comment: `call` takes a list of strings.  See the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run

Comment: Don't try to generate JSON like this; use `json.dumps`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be clearer to pass a list to `subprocess.call`:

```
import json
import subprocess

someVariable = 'hello'
hive_ql = 'CREATE VIEW user_balance AS SELECT NAME, LOB,ACCOUNT,BALANCE FROM csvtable'  # noqa

subprocess.call([
    'curl',
    '-H',
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    '-X',
    'PUT',
    '-d',
    json.dumps({
      'name': str(someVariable),
      'hive_ql': hive_ql
    }),
    'localhost:someport/api'
])
```

Comment: When I run this, I get 'curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information'

Comment: Try removing `shell=True`

Comment: ^That worked, thanks! Any idea why that might have been the issue?

Comment: Looks like ```shell=True``` is only needed if subprocess is calling a single line (as opposed to an array as in this example)

Answer (score 1):

You aren't calling `.format`, it's inside your string.  Try this:

```
subprocess.call('''curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X PUT -d '{"name": "{}", "hive_ql": "CREATE VIEW user_balance AS SELECT NAME, LOB,ACCOUNT,BALANCE FROM csvtable"}' localhost:someport/api'''.format(someVariable), shell=True)
```

As it stands, the JSON you're trying to decode is:

```
{
  "name": "{}".format(someVariable),
  "hive_ql": "CREATE VIEW user_balance AS SELECT NAME, LOB,ACCOUNT,BALANCE FROM csvtable"
}
```

because python is just treating `.format(someVariable)` as part of the string and not replacing it with the value of someVariable, and clearly it is not valid JSON to have that hanging onto the end of a string.

Edit: I forgot to escape the brackets; try this instead:

```
subprocess.call('''curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X PUT -d '{{"name": "{}", "hive_ql": "CREATE VIEW user_balance AS SELECT NAME, LOB,ACCOUNT,BALANCE FROM csvtable"}}' localhost:someport/api'''.format(someVariable), shell=True)
```

Comment: When I ran this, I got KeyError: '"name"'